# SAVING Open Office files to DESKTOP

Tags: open-office

I just installed APACHE Open Office. Open Office saves to the `~/Documents` folder. Which, for me, is extremely to find. That's the apparently ONLY (default) setting Open Office allows.  How can I save my documents to my Desktop (`~/Desktop`) instead of the documents folder?

Comment: Chill. Doesn't it ask you where to save it when you press Command-S on your Mac? If not, try File > Save As and it should give you a menu to save it _anywhere_.

Comment: How is ~/Documents "extremely hard to find?"  In Finder, click on Go, then Documents.  You can also press `Shift-Command-O` and it will open it from anywhere.  I'm not seeing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default path in Preferences:

[image]